# why ubuntu 18.04LTS installer crashes after detecting hardware

Tags: ubuntu, installation, installer

I have ASUS X540U laptop and I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04LTS on it but every time the installer reach the detecting hardware stage the progress bar freeze and after couple of seconds it crashes. I did searched for solution on Google and found that I have to disable secure boot but it is already disabled. how to solve this problem Note: I am installing Ubuntu side by side windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop!

In the black GRUB menu that shows briefly, when highlighting the installation option or the "try Ubuntu" option:

- press the `e` key (for edit)
- where it says "splash ..." put "splash **pci=noaer** ..."
- press `ctrl+x` key combination to boot

After installation, open the Terminal application and type:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` (or maybe grub-efi-amd64 ?)

There, press Enter and when it says "Linux default command line" you should add `pci=noaer`, so it should end up like this:

`quiet splash pci=noaer`

If you don't do that quickly after installation, your hard disk will get full because of log messages in `/var/log/`.

More info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173

Comment: I had the same problem with ubuntu 20 and intel i9. The new thing, besides the processor, was a wifi card. The instruction that was provided solved the problem