# Ubuntu setup crashes and random points during and before setup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, crash

I bought a brand new ThinkCentre M920x Tiny (which is a mini computer) and wanted to install Ubuntu on it.
I flahed a USB stick useing Etcher on my Windowas 10 machine.

Then I started the setup on my new ThinkCenter.
Then at random points during my the setup most of the time after selecting "Ubuntu" from the grub menu.
Sometimes I can made it to selecting the keyboard layout. But the install process never starts.

The "crash" usualy looks like this.
Keyboard an mouse freeze, fan of the computer turns on and after about 3 seconds it just reboots.

I started with the usual things:

1. Using another memory stick, using yet another memory stick
2. Disabled UEFI, Enables Legacy BIOS
3. Disabled Secureboot
4. Tried the Dayli build from Ubuntu 21.04
5. Tried to disable logging using pci=noaer in grub ([why ubuntu 18.04LTS installer crashes after detecting hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/1325700/why-ubuntu-18-04lts-installer-crashes-after-detecting-hardware))
6. Did a hardwaretest (memtest)

And all this in various combinations.

Now I am done with my knowldege and have to ask for help here :)
Maybe one of you encountered similiar problems and push me into the right direction to solve this.

//update
After fiddeling around with various bios settings and an Arch Linux - Live test enviroment I figured out more.
After a few minutes the kernel throws an MCE exception:
mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 2: Machine Check: 0 Bank 0:
Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Umx.jpg

But that error occures ONLY when I multi CPU (not hyperthreading) is enabled in BIOS. When I disable multi CPU in bios the system runs stable.
Unfortunately then only one CPU is available to the OS.

Comment: How much memory is on this mini-computer?  What's the minimum RAM requirement to install the version of Ubuntu you're trying to install?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Intel 16GB of ram, should be more then enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is certified for Ubuntu in the article
[Linux for Personal Systems](https://support.lenovo.com/be/en/solutions/pd031426),
although this was for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 Bit and using as CPU the
Intel i7-8700.

It is again certified for
[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64 Bit](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201906-27143),
using as CPU the Intel Pentium Gold G5420.

In both certifications there are red flags, starting with
"Pre-installed by manufacturer"
and also containing the following notes by Lenovo:

> 1. **The system is available in some regions with a special image of Ubuntu pre-installed by the manufacturer**. It takes advantage of the
>    hardware features for this system and may include additional software.
>    You should check when buying the system whether this is an option.
> 2. **Standard images of Ubuntu may not work at all on the system or may not work well**, though Canonical and computer manufacturers will
>    try to certify the system with future standard releases of Ubuntu.

So it seems that a special version of Ubuntu, created by Lenovo,
is the only one that works on this computer.
I also note that this version is only certified
for specific CPU types (I don't know if your CPU is one of them).

There are plenty of problem reports to be found for the installation of standard
Ubuntu. Below are some examples:

- [Bug #1883153 : Ubuntu 20.04 freezes at/after login screen, Lenovo ThinkCentre M920x](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1883153)
- [Ubuntu on Lenovo ThinkCentre M920x Tiny](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/view/2713/5066598)
- [Linux on a Lenovo ThinkCentre M920x Tiny](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/linux-on-a-lenovo-thinkcentre-m920x-tiny.31911/)

Some reports of success included the replacement of the RAM sticks
(although none reported the model used).
Others, like yourself, noted that it works with disabled multi-CPU.

My conclusion is that your chances of success are slim. I can still suggest:

- Ask Lenovo Support for an Ubuntu installation that is adapted to your model
- Try the earlier Ubuntu versions for which it is supposedly certified
- Try to install with multi-CPU disabled and re-enable it after installation
- Give up - I don't know if buying more
  [certified RAM](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/thinkcentre-m920x-tiny#memory)
  is worth the cost.